# Package not importing when invoking Python script remotely

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have a python 2.7 script that executes LOCALLY perfectly fine.

The problem occurs ONLY when I attempt to invoke the script remotely (SSH):

```
ssh user@server "python script.py"

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 18, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests*
```

After doing a little bit of research, I have tried manually inserting the absolute the path to the "requests" library using sys.path.insert before importing the library:

```
sys.path.insert(1,'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg')
import requests
```

I even confirmed the path to the package got added succesfully by printing the sys.path when invoking the script remotely:

```
print '\n'.join(sys.path)
```

Result:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.9.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python27.zip
/usr/local/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

However, I am still getting the "ImportError: No module named requests" no matter what.

Can you help me understand what am I missing?

Again, this script does find the library without issue and runs perfectly fine when I execute the script locally.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the 'remote' system's configuration? If you are on Ubuntu, you can `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and `sudo -H pip install requests` to get it to work assuming it is the only issue.

Comment: after you ssh can you run the `python` command and then do `import requests` to see if that is working?

Answer (score 0):

`requests` is a non-standard Python library.  Make sure it is installed on the remote box you are attempting to execute the script on.

On the remote, execute from the shell:

```
easy_install pip
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to run the same script on the same machine, but once from a local shell and once from a remote shell (with `ssh`).

If this is the case, when you use the remote shell, be sure that you have the environment properly setup.

This may boil down to just setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable correctly.

In your case, this would be:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH
```

You may need to add more paths to it.

When I have this sort of issues, I usually run a python shell from the working environment and check where the files are taken from, so I can be sure the correct entries are set in the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ ipython

In [1]: import requests
In [2]: print requests.__file__
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.pyc
```

For this example, I would add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to my `PYTHONPATH` if I was not able to `import requests` correctly.